# AndroidActivity extends GameBaseActivity crashes

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am having a class

> public class GameActivity extends Activity implements
>   GLSurfaceView.Renderer, OnTouchListener{

The code does not have any problems, all needed methods are implemented. When I start the Activity it crashes with the following message:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{[left out].GameActivity}:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "...GameActivity"
>   on path [...]

I want to integreate the Google Game Service and Achievements in my game. Therefore I added the libary project and the `GameBaseUtils` as projects and also checkt that they should be exported inside my generated apk file. It compiles, the .jar for the google play services is also uploaded and will b e found. All includes are working. But when I start the game, it crashed immediately with the error message above.

I followed the tutorials on developers.android.com https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Here is my Manifest

> ```
> <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
> package=""
> android:versionCode="1"
> android:versionName="1.0" >
>
> <uses-sdk
>     android:minSdkVersion="8"
>     android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
>
> <!-- 
>   Tell the market, that the the app requires at least OpenGLES 2.0 
>   This is not really the truth but it will decrease the rate of error
>  -->
> <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" 
>     android:required="true" />
>
> <!-- Maybe not neccessary -->
> <!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> -->
>
>
> <application 
>     android:allowBackup="true"
>     android:icon="@drawable/launcher_icon"
>     android:label="@string/app_name"
>     android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
>     android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape" >
>
>     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
>     android:value="13465798" />
>
>
>     <activity
>         android:name="GameActivity"
>         android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape">
>         <intent-filter>
>             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
>             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
>         </intent-filter>
>     </activity>
>     <!-- For the implementation of Adds in this App -->
> </application>
>
> </manifest>
> ```

Edit: Locat output

> 07-21 01:13:47.730: W/dalvikvm(22578): Unable to resolve superclass of
>   LGameActivity; (1182)  07-21 01:13:47.730:
>   W/dalvikvm(22578): Link of class
>   'L/GameActivity;' failed  07-21 01:13:47.730:
>   D/AndroidRuntime(22578): Shutting down VM  07-21 01:13:47.730:
>   W/dalvikvm(22578): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception
>   (group=0x4159f930)  07-21 01:13:47.746: E/AndroidRuntime(22578): FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main  07-21 01:13:47.746: E/AndroidRuntime(22578):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{GameActivity}:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "GameActivity" on path:
>   .apk  07-21 01:13:47.746:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(22578):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
>   07-21 01:13:47.746: E/AndroidRuntime(22578):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
>   07-21 01:13:47.746: E/AndroidRuntime(22578):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)  07-21
>   01:13:47.746: E/AndroidRuntime(22578):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234) 
>   07-21 01:13:47.746: E/AndroidRuntime(22578):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)  07-21
>   01:13:47.746: E/AndroidRuntime(22578):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 07-21 01:13:47.746:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(22578):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)  07-21
>   01:13:47.746: E/AndroidRuntime(22578):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)  07-21
>   01:13:47.746: E/AndroidRuntime(22578):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)  07-21 01:13:47.746:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(22578):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>   07-21 01:13:47.746: E/AndroidRuntime(22578):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)  07-21
>   01:13:47.746: E/AndroidRuntime(22578):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 07-21 01:13:47.746:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(22578): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   Didn't find class "GameActivity" on path:
>   -1.apk  07-21 01:13:47.746:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(22578):  at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
>   07-21 01:13:47.746: E/AndroidRuntime(22578):  at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)  07-21
>   01:13:47.746: E/AndroidRuntime(22578):    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)  07-21
>   01:13:47.746: E/AndroidRuntime(22578):    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054) 
>   07-21 01:13:47.746: E/AndroidRuntime(22578):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
>   07-21 01:13:47.746: E/AndroidRuntime(22578):  ... 11 more

Comment: can you please post the complete LogCat ?

Comment: I've added the locat output

Comment: inside the `<application>` tag in manifest did you try something like: `<activity
        android:name=.GameActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape">`

Comment: This was an error due to a try of removing the app name and package names. In the Manifest of my project the package and the Name are right. I will edit to the original manifest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the error:

I had to mark both projects I am using for the app (GameBaseUtils and google-play-services_lib) as a libary project and add them to android libaries I want to use. The rest is handled by android on its own.